# Making a script to take input from a user and use error checking to test if two arguments were entered: Linux

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

My Linux class just started to begin scripting and I am having trouble with one of my questions. The question is as follows: Use a script to take two numbers as arguments and output their sum using bc.

This is my first script. To get the script to execute you need to do chmod +x filename

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter in a numeric value: " num1
read -p "Enter in a second numeric value: " num2
if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then   
    echo "Enter in two numeric arguments"
else
    echo "The sum of the entered values are: "
    echo "$num1 + $num2"|bc
fi
```

I keep running into an error. When I enter in two values it displays "Enter in two numeric arguments". It shouldn't do that because if I enter in two values, the if statement will evaluate to false and go to the else statement. Is my logic wrong or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: You don't need `read` if the script is intended to be run like `filename 3 4`; the arguments will be found in `$1` and `$2`, respectively. You can use them directly, or assign them to more meaningful names, e.g., `num1=$1`.

Comment: We need to take input from a user and not a file

Comment: You said "as arguments". That's what @chepner is talking about. 
Your arguments from the command line where you execute the script as `script 20 30` will be $1 and $2 in the code. You don't need the read. Just use the given numeric names, or assign them to num1 & num2.

Comment: Normally I would complain along the lines of "Thanks for showing us your homework" but you've actually tried to solve the problem and done some research! Good job! +1

Comment: If, however, you are supposed to use `read` to get user input *after* the script starts to run, then `$#` isn't relevant. You need to examine the values of `num1` and `num2` to see if they are non-empty (at a minimum; parsing strings to see if they are valid numbers, as opposed to simply trying them to see what happens, is non-trivial.)

Comment: By definition, `num1` and `num2` have values if you reach a line of the script following the second `read`; that command blocks until the user enters a value. That value could be any valid string, though, including the empty string (if, e.g., the user just hits enter).

Comment: `Numbers as arguments` - What kind of numbers? Are they integers?  Are they decimals? Your question is a bit terse at the moment. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop and `break`.

```
n=0                                                                                                                                                      
ex=""                                                                                                                                                    
while [ 1 ]                                                                                                                                              
do                                                                                                                                                       
 read -p "Enter read in a numeric value" num                                                                                                              
  n=$(( n + 1))                                                                                                                                            

 if [[ $n -eq 2 ]]                                                                                                                                        
  then                                                                                                                                                     
    ex=${ex}${num}                                                                                                                                           
    echo "Sum of the two values are"                                                                                                                         
    echo ${ex}  | bc                                                                                                                                         
  break                                                                                                                                                    

 else                                                                                                                                                     
  ex=$num" +  "                                                                                                                                            
 fi                                                                                                                                                       
done
```